# How to lowercase a string except for first character with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I lowercase a string except for first character with PowerShell? This code crashes:

```
Get-ChildItem -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_FullName.substring(0,1).toupper()+$_FullName.substring(1).tolower()}
```

What do I need to change to fix it?

Comment: "Crashes, Fix how" isn't very useful. **Always** post the exact error message that you got, it makes life a lot easier for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem is that you are missing a dot between `$_` and the property.

Second problem is that the `FullName` property is the full path of the object including the drive and path. So uppercasing the first character simply makes the drive letter uppercase (which it was already) and nothing changes. Using the `Name` property instead will work as that doesn't have a path at all and without a path `Rename-Item` will use the path from the original item.

Third lesser problem is that you can just filter Get-ChildItem to give only files and don't need the second step at all:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.substring(0,1).toupper()+$_.Name.substring(1).tolower()}
```

Rather than just uppercasing the first letter, you might actually want to uppercase separate words in the filename. If so you can do this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName  {(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Name)}
```

[Edit] However that also uppercases the extension, so actually this is better:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.BaseName) +
        $_.Extension.ToLower()}
```

Comment: With your help i sattle to use Get-ChildItem -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.substring(0,1).toupper()+$_.Name.substring(1).tolower()} i don't get the -file parameter in your sample to work....

Comment: I think the `-File` parameter may have been new in Powershell 3.0, if you're still using an older version you should consider upgrading.